# Could you publish something handwritten?

Tags: publishing

Recently, a friend of mine wrote a book, handwritten. She doesn't have the heart to type the three-hundred pages that she painfully wrote for two years. I really want to help her, can anyone tell me a way to publish handwritten text?

Comment: Had she never scratched out, or overwritten anything? Had she never created some patchworks of reorganized paragraphs, sentences? Or, is it all there, to be seen? Had she never gotten taken away and slid into a less readable handwriting style? If she had never gotten taken away into a less readable handwriting style, how can one assume that it's the best possible prose in there? Her priority seems to have been neat handwriting, not destroying and rebuilding her story several times... Am I wrong thinking that?

Comment: Publishers don't even accept printed works anymore, let alone hand-written ones. Hire a typist to copy this into a file, or do it yourself.

Comment: She always first make notes, organized them, draft them, and then finally put them onto the real paper. That why it took her a long time.

Comment: Then it's something like an audiobook read by the author themselves — only in writing; isn't it? :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For anyone who has found they have written a whole bunch and just don't have the heart to convert, it's good to know there's ways around that.

Here's how to help:

1. hire a transcription service. (is about from $240-$900 total for that depending on the service)
2. buy a talk-to-text program that converts speech into text.
3. something new that scans handwritten into text: https://www.popsci.com/digitize-handwritten-notes/

But no, to answer your question, no sane publisher would ever take a handwritten manuscript. Unless she was already published and famous.